# Powertip on dynamically loaded content without running script again or loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm using the jQuery plugin [PowerTip](https://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/) to show tooltips on hover. I initialize it with `$('.tooltip').powerTip()` and this works great on already loaded content, but if I dynamically load `<div class="tooltip" data-powertip="Hey">Hey</div>`, I have to run the `$('.tooltip').powerTip()` function again, which seems like a waste, especially if I have hundreds of these. Is it possible to do something like this? :

1)

```
$(document).powerTip('.tooltip', {})
```

or

2)

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.tooltip', function(e) {
    $(this).powerTip()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems sound the only issue is you might need a callback function to trigger the popup because triggering the popup and initialising it happen at the same time (which could be problematic)

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter','.tooltip', function(event) {
    $(event.target).powerTip();
    var delay = 250; //  1/4 of a second
    setTimeout(() => {
       $(event.target).tooltip('show')
    }, delay);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is delegate any different than on? I basically tried what you mentioned but with on and had the issue you described. How would a solution with a callback look? Thank you //edit. Just googled and found out that delegate is deprecated and replaced by on.

Comment: Yes I switched it to `.on` thank you.  I added code with slight delay

Comment: I think you’ve switched places of .tooltip and mouseenter. That is what I tried that doesn’t work unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try it as soon as I can.

Comment: `.tooltip('show')` should be `.powerTip('show')` I assume. It seems like stuff is bubbling up and after a while I get `e is null` from the powerTip code. Not sure it will work unfortunately.